# How to display a variable defined in a php file, only using the URL?

Tags: php, url

I would like to know if it's possible to call a .php page and at the same time to display the value of a variable which is in this same page.

Example:

```
<?php
$cf['files']['file1']="test";?>
```

How can I make the value "test" to be displayed ? (without changing anything in the code of the page, no `echo` etc.) Is it possible at least ?

Thank you

Comment: no echo; get the file's content then.

Comment: you're going to have to define that *"only using the URL"* part.

Comment: ok, you're not responding. someone gave you answer; take it up with them, I've left the question.

Comment: It is not possible to force a PHP page to display variables unless it is coded to do so or vulnerable to some XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. It would be a huge security problem if you could display the contents of a variable of a foreign PHP-generated page.

Comment: that's not what they're asking. Answer the question. Otherwise, this is a comment. and what foreign page?

Comment: The OP wants to "call a .php page" (I presume that means opening it in a browser - or calling a `file_get_contents()` on it, if you want) and getting the contents of a PHP variable, that is used inside the page. Given that he cannot modify the code of the page to include `echo`, I deduce he's trying to do this with a page not under his control (a "foreign" page).

Comment: I posted a few comments up there and asking for clarification but they either left the question only to return at a later date, or I don't know what they're doing. I've left the question. They can take it up with your answer.